# Can we solve factorial of a number using map reduce program?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can we solve the factorial of a number using map-reduce program? If yes then how mapper and reducer will interact?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible. What doubts do you have? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use mapreduce for just one number, but rather billions of numbers

The factorial of any number can be found by a simple for loop

MapReduce doesn't change that fact

And this would be a map-only task since no reduction is needed